# Одинаковые свойства в объекте

Tags: javascript

Как можно пройтись циклом по объекту, у которого есть свойства с одинаковым именем? Или тут никак, лишь через массив? Объект такой:

```
obj = {
  name: {},
  name: {}
}
```

Comment: Сегодня вроде бы не день розыгрыша...

Comment: Понятно, значит нельзя.

Comment: @rimlin, у меня две переменные: `i = 1; i = 2;`. Как вывести значения обеих?

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Если существуют свойства с одинаковым именем - последнее перезапишет предыдущее.

```
var obj = {
   name: 'Egor',
   name: 'Andrey'
};


alert(obj.name);// Andrey
```

Answer (score 1):

Хех, если в объекте уникальные названия свойств, то можно вывернуть всё наизнанку:

```
obj = {
  ['Вася']: 'name',
  ['Андрей']: 'name'
}
for(var key in obj){
  if(obj[key] == 'name'){
    // do some thing with key
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Одинаковые ключи в объекте будут перезатирать сами себя — это верно. Эту задачу можно решить вложив объекты в массив:

```
var obj = [
  {name: 'Anna'},
  {name: 'Mike'}
]
```

Дальше проходите перебором с условиями по ключам.

```
for (key in obj){
 // сделаем проверку на случай если в массиве есть строки 
 if(typeof obj[key] == 'object'){  
    for(item in obj[key]){
        // отбор объектов с ключём 'name'
        if(item = 'name'){  
              // выведем значение name в консоль
              console.log(obj[key][item]) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Можно делать «мультивложенные» массивы и объекты для сложных структур:

```
var obj = [
  {name: 'Anna', age: '23', friend: true},
  {name: 'Mike', age: '32', friend: false},
  {tags: ['name', 'age','language']},
  'just string'
]
```

И проходить по ним вложенными циклами с проверками:

```
for (key in obj){
 // берём только объекты с нужным ключом
 if(typeof obj[key] == 'object' && obj[key].name){ 
    // пройдёмся по объекту и выведем его значения в консоль
    for(item in obj[key]){
        if(item = 'name'){
            console.log('Имя: ' + obj[key][item])
            }
        }
        if(item = 'age'){
            console.log('Возраст: ' + obj[key][item])
            }
        }
        if(obj[key].friend){
            console.log("в друзьях")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Логичнее было бы так

```js
    var obj = {
    name: [
    "Валя",
    "Таня"
    ]
    }
   alert(obj.name)
```